# howto control recording of a webcam

Tags: .net, io, webcam, vlc

I have a nice work to do for a customer. He has a lab where he has a webcam that records things that happens in the lab work. He has a PLC that controls the lab work.

Now we would like to control the start and stop of recording, and save it to a file. The plc gives the signals for start and stop. The signals are electrical, +24V for true and 0V for false.

My idea is to use a digital input card to the PC, use VLC for the webcam, make a Windows application (use Visual Studio C# or VB) that reads the digital inputs and uses the VLC API to steer start/stop of recording.

Do you have any experience of this kind of job? Or other info that can direct me? I'm very thankful for your ideas and help.

Regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

Most PLCs allow you to access them from ethernet, or a specifically designed card.

Either way you get some software that will let you read and write to addresses on the PLC

So no electrical doings required.

Can't say more without knowing the make and model of the PLC.

It used to be something called RSView for Allen Bradley, but usually you get something with the PLC for doing it.

You can also get SCADA software for the PLCs, though that would be over the top for something this limited, howevre if they were prepared to go buy it (or they already have it), you could collect experimental data off the PLC to got with the video....

Only did allen bradley myself, and that was back in 99, so I won't be too much help on the detailed side.

Comment: Yes, ethernet access may be easier. The PLC is ABB AC800M and it communicates with profibus and maybe someting more... have to check that.

Comment: OPC is the way they usually describe it now, 'ole for process control'. Before my time, I had to use DDE.